# How do I specify the username of Wi-Fi on Arduino Yun?

Tags: arduino

When I am trying to configure the onboard Wi-Fi, [the tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc13) says to enter the password, but it does not have any place to enter the username for the Wi-Fi network. I even went into the advanced section there.

Also I could not find anything that would help me enter the username. Is there anything that I am missing? Where should I enter username for the Wi-Fi?

PS: I am using the college Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 2):

From the tutorial you linked:

> The Yún has the ability to act as an Access Point, but it can also connect to an existing network. These instructions walk you through connecting your Yún to a wireless network. The Yún can connect to unencrypted networks, as well as networks that support WEP, WPA, and WPA2 encryption.

If you have to enter a username and password to connect to the your college Wi-Fi network - your college is probably not using WEP, WPA, and WPA2 in the normal 'home Wi-Fi' configuration.

To connect to a WPA2 network you need the network to be available an a password.

Chances are your college is using something like "WPA2-Enterprise" that involves a server on the back end to authenticate each client individually as they connect, hence the reason you need a user name.

Short answer: It looks like you can't connect your Arduino to the college network. Perhaps you can tether it to your laptop?